# PHP sort FLOAT & INTEGER values in array - rsort()

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, floating-point, integer

I am having issues properly sorting numbers with FLOAT using `rsort();` I searched google and StackOverflow for hours and did not find a solution.

Issues arise when the integers are the same, but float is different.

Example `array( 1.7, 1, 1.9, 1.4,)` - notice they are all **1** with a decimal.

Here is my code:

```
$a = 1.7; 
$b = 1;
$c = 1.9;
$d = 1.4;
$num = [$a,$b,$c,$d];
rsort($num);

$high_name = [
  $a => "a",
  $b => "b",
  $c => "c",
  $d => "d",
];

$on1 = $high_name[$num[0]];
$on2 = $high_name[$num[1]];
$on3 = $high_name[$num[2]];
$on4 = $high_name[$num[3]];
```

I need to get a letter that corresponds to highest number in the array.
Logically, **$on1** should be = **C**

but if I do:

```
echo "<br>on1 = $on1";
echo "<br>on2 = $on2";
echo "<br>on3 = $on3";
echo "<br>on4 = $on4";
```

I get:

```
on1 = d
on2 = d
on3 = d
on4 = d
```

I need to know what the highest number is in the array, be it Integer or float.

The result I'm looking for:

```
on1 = c
on2 = a
on3 = d
on4 = b
```

Thanks all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"I am having issues properly sorting numbers with FLOAT using rsort();"_ - no, you don't. Sorting that $num array via rsort works perfectly fine. And what your _actual_ issue is here, I can't tell, because the description of what you actually want to achieve, is too confusing.

Comment: Start with a `var_dump($high_name);`, to get an idea where your _actual_ problem lies; then go read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and pay attention to what it has to say about floats as array keys.

Comment: @CBore - yes that seems to be the issue. I do I go about it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes / keys can be an integer or a string.  So if it's not a string and not an integer it will be cast to an integer.  In your case, all values are cast to integer `1` and since indexes are unique you get the last one defined, which is `d`.

If you can't define them as string originally:

```
$a = "1.7";
```

Then do it when defining the array:

```
$num = ["$a", "$b", "$c", "$d"];
```

Or when accessing:

```
$on1 = $high_name[(string)$num[0]];
// or
$on1 = $high_name["$num[0]"];
```

Comment: But the same thing goes for trying to access the values using `$high_name[$num[0]]` as well - if `$num[0]` is still a float like `1.7`, then it will access `$high_name[1]`. These need to be made strings to begin with, or casted at this point, as well.

Comment: CBore - so I have to convert $a, $b, $c, $d to a string before I sort them?

Comment: The sorting isn't the problem, read my text.  @CBroe edited thanks...